# Exiting function under some condition

Tags: bash

I have the following function that loops over short and long options.  It there is a match with a short option, I exit the for first `for` loop.  But I also want to exit the function, and skip testing for long options.  How can I handle this ?

```
  xerxex ()
  {

   for short_opt in "${glob_pary[@]}"
   do
     pthis
     pthat 
     [[ something ]] &&  break
   done
   
   exit_function 

   for long_opt in "${glob_qary[@]}"  # [L]
   do
     qthis
     qthat
     [[ something ]] &&  break
   done

  }
```

Comment: Did you consider using `getopts` or `getopt`? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/402377/10622916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` leaves the function; `break` just jumps out of the loop.

EDIT: don't `exit`!  It terminates the process; if you're interactively running a script, it closes the window...

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code is somewhat unclear, but one option might be to test for a non-zero number of arguments before entering that code block:

```
xerxex ()
{
  if [ ${#glob_pary[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    for short_opt in "${glob_pary[@]}"
    do
      pthis
      pthat 
      [[ something ]]
    done
  elif [ ${#glob_qary[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    for long_opt in "${glob_qary[@]}"  # [L]
    do
      qthis
      qthat
      [[ something ]]
    done
  fi
}
```